# hacer dos filtros WHERE pero solo se cumple uno

Tags: mysql, sql

No funciona la siguiente consulta completamente al parecer solo trabaja el WHERE desde las fechas y el estado lo deja por fuera sin validez. Lo que busco es que muestre solo el batch 3, con el Where de fecha que funciona bien. Alguna ayuda.

```
SELECT batch.id_batch, 
       batch.fecha_programacion, 
       batch.numero_orden, 
       batch.numero_orden, 
       batch.id_producto as referencia, 
       batch.numero_lote, batch.estado 
FROM batch 
WHERE (batch.estado > 2 AND batch.estado < 4) 
AND  batch.fecha_programacion  
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
OR batch.fecha_programacion <= CURRENT_DATE() 
ORDER BY batch.id_batch DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dado el rango que expones: `WHERE (batch.estado > 2 AND batch.estado < 4)` ¿no simplemente debería ser: `WHERE batch.estado = 3`?

Comment: Si tienes razón desde la perspectiva que lo ves. lo que sucede es que hay dos registros que deben estar en el rango y es 3 y 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solucion después de dar muchas vueltas. Al hacer la sentencia primero se debe ejecutar el WHERE de fechas y luego el del estado, lo que actualmente hace al revés

```
SELECT batch.id_batch, 
   batch.fecha_programacion, 
   batch.numero_orden, 
   batch.numero_orden, 
   batch.id_producto as referencia, 
   batch.numero_lote, batch.estado 
FROM batch 
WHERE batch.fecha_programacion  
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
OR batch.fecha_programacion <= CURRENT_DATE() AND (batch.estado > 2 AND batch.estado < 4) 
ORDER BY batch.id_batch DESC
```

Comment: No necesariamente

Answer (score 0):

Debes de checar siempre el [orden de precedencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) de las comparaciones lógicas.

En el caso de AND esta se ejecuta antes de la comparación OR. Pues AND tiene mayor orden de precedencia; entonces ahí podrías tener tu problema de condiciones